# Rails 3.1 Record Counter for Homepage

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, caching, activerecord, counter

I had a quick question that's been bugging me. I'd like to place a counter on the homepage of my Rails 3.1.rc4 site to advertise how many micro-blogging posts are in the site's database. The problem is this number is going to grow to be huge over time and I don't want to have to use something like `Post.find(:all).count`. So this is where my question lies: is there an easy, cache-able (for let's say 8 hours), and non-resource intensive way to display a count of records in a database? I'm using ActiveRecord and Heroku hosting (Cedar Stack with no Varnish cache).

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, use `Post.count` and if you want to cache the result for 8 hours, do:

```
Rails.cache.fetch(:posts_count, :expires_in => 8.hours) do
  Post.count
end
```

Comment: Thanks ream88! If I wanted to expire that cache for some reason, what would be the best way to do it?

Comment: Add `:force => true` to the fetch call or call `Rails.cache.delete(:posts_count)`.

Comment: Cool, and just to confirm: this should go in my controller and be called in the view as `@posts_count` or as `:posts_count`?

Comment: Year in the controller or in the helper and do `@posts_count = Rails.cache.fetch(:posts_count, :expires_in => 8.hours) { Post.count }`, so it's even a nice one-liner.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `Post.count` which does `select count(id) from posts;` in SQL.